# Javascript-code doesn't work with Facebook Graph Api and FQL

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying out the Graph Api and FQL from Facebook, but i can't get my code to work.

```
function getUserMovies2() {
   FB.api('/me/movies?fields=name,genre,release_date,picture,likes', function(response) {
     console.log('Got Movies: ', response);

     if (!response.error) {
       var markup = '';

       var movies = response.data;

       for (var i=0; i < movies.length && i < 1; i++) {
         var movie = movies[i];

            FB.api('fql', { q: 'SELECT name FROM page WHERE genre = ' + movie.genre + 'LIMIT 1' }, function (response)
            {   
                //do something with the response
                // show name of the movie...
                markup = '<p> Suggested Movie:'+ response + '</p>';

            });
       }
      document.getElementById('user-movies').innerHTML = markup;
     }
   });
 }
```

It should show the first movie name (page) with the same genre of the first movie that i liked. This is just a test, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to have a space between movie.genre and LIMIT:

```
'SELECT name FROM page WHERE genre = ' + movie.genre + ' LIMIT 1'
```

Otherwise, Facebook is going to think that you are looking for a genre equal to `movie.genreLIMIT`.

If you tell me what response Facebook is returning, that would be even more helpful.